# detect a screen touch outside the spinnersearch view

Tags: xamarin.android, android-spinner, touch-event

i have created an android app via xamarin.android. i have a multispinnersearch in a fragment and when opened normally, all the items inside it are preselected. but i had a problem. if the user touches the screen outside the spinner, the latter closes and all the items get into my list. i don't want that. unless he clicks "ok" in the spinner, no items should be taken to my list. so i tried to handle the touch event to prevent the selection of items on screen touch but it didn't work. here are the codes i tried:

```
  public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (ev.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                View v = CurrentFocus;
                if (v is MultiSpinnerSearch)
                {
                    Rect outRect = new Rect();
                    v.GetGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
                    if (!outRect.Contains((int)ev.RawX, (int) ev.RawY))
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "shgsg", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.DispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }
```

i tried this in my main activity but i didn't work. then i tried this in my fragment on the ontouch listener interface:

```
 if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                if (labors_dropdown.IsFocused == true)
                {
                    Android.Graphics.Rect rect = new Rect();
                    labors_dropdown.GetGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
                    if (!rect.Contains((int)e.RawX, (int)e.RawY))
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this.Context, "gfgf", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

it didn't work too, what should i do? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below method:

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        if (ev.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            View v = (MultiSpinnerSearch)FindViewById<MultiSpinnerSearch>(Resource.Id.xxxxx);           
            if (!IsTouchPointInView(v, (int)ev.GetX(), (int)ev.GetY()))
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "shgsg", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
        }

        return base.DispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

private bool IsTouchPointInView(View targetView, int currentX, int currentY)
    {
        if (targetView == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int[] localtion = new int[2];
        targetView.GetLocationOnScreen(localtion);
        int left = localtion[0];
        int top = localtion[1];
        int right = left + targetView.MeasuredWidth;
        int bottom = top + targetView.MeasuredHeight;
        if (currentY >= top && currentY <= bottom && currentX >= left
          && currentX <= right)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```